# Pointers in structures and use of typedef in structure

Tags: c, pointers, structure, nodes

```
struct node

{

int data;

struct node *addr;

};

typedef struct node *NODE;   NODE start; //statement 1

typedef struct node NODE;    NODE *start;//statement 2
```

What is the difference between statement 1 and statement 2?

Comment: Use three backticks to delimit code, not three apostrophes: `\`` instead of `'`.  Also, it's spelled `typedef`.

Comment: The first is generally harder to understand and maintain, and tend to lead to problems when you (and others) forget (or don't know) that `NODE` is an alias for a pointer. One common example is to use `sizeof(NODE)` (in e.g. calls to `malloc`) instead of `sizeof(struct node)`. In the first case `sizeof(NODE) != sizeof(struct node)`.

Comment: Both statement 1 and 2 declare an uninitialized variable that is a node pointer. Statement 2 is usually preferred since it doesn't "hide" the fact that NODE is a pointer behind the `typedef`.